# Python authlib flask - how to do authorize_redirect explicitly?

Tags: python, flask, authlib

I have "code grant flow" login with the authlib flask integration working nicely:

```
redirect_uri = url_for('authorize', _external=True)
return oauth.myOauth2.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri)
```

For some reason I decided I want to try to make the redirect a bit more visible. Show users my app for a moment before redirecting to a login page that may be more unfamiliar for some.

Now this kind of works:

```
redirect_uri = url_for('authorize', _external=True)
aurl = oauth.myOauth2.create_authorization_url(redirect_uri)
# what to do with aurl['state']?
return render_template('redirect.html', delay=2,
                       redirect_notice='Redirecting to login', 
                       redirect_url=aurl['url'])
```

However, when I'm redirected back to "authorize" after login, I get `authlib.integrations.base_client.errors.MismatchingStateError: mismatching_state: CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response.` which I presume is because I did not save `aurl['state']`.

But how can I actually do that? I'm having a hard time teasing out how authorize_redirect does it.
Maybe there is a better way altogether? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to get your job done:

1. extract url from `.authorize_redirect`:

```py
redirect_uri = url_for('authorize', _external=True)
resp = oauth.myOauth2.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri)
url = resp.headers.get('Location')
return render_template('redirect.html', delay=2,
                       redirect_notice='Redirecting to login', 
                       redirect_url=url)
```

2. use `.save_authorize_data` to save CSRF and other data:

```
redirect_uri = url_for('authorize', _external=True)
rv = oauth.myOauth2.create_authorization_url(redirect_uri)
oauth.myOauth2.save_authorize_data(request, redirect_uri=redirect_uri, **rv)
return render_template('redirect.html', delay=2,
                       redirect_notice='Redirecting to login', 
                       redirect_url=rv['url'])
```

You can learn it from: https://github.com/lepture/authlib/blob/master/authlib/integrations/flask_client/remote_app.py#L51

Comment: Most excellent :-) I should have thought to inspect the response. I guess 2. would be more "correct", but I like 1. for the simplicity. I actually had "def authorize_redirect()" right in front of me last night but somehow missed seeing how to use save_authorize_data()!