# Python authlib flask - how to do password grant flow correctly?

Tags: python, flask, authlib

I have "password grant flow" login with the authlib flask integration working nicely:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def login():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('login.html')
    else:
        try:
            token = oauth.myOauth2.fetch_access_token(username=request.form.get('username'),
                                                      password=request.form.get('password'))
        except OAuthError as e:
            if e.description:
                flash(e.description)
                return render_template('login.html')
            raise
```

However, in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62193044/better-examples-of-authlib-oauth-client-use-with-a-flask-app) I was advised not to use `fetch_access_token` like this as it's not documented for the flask integration, and to use `authorize_access_token` instead. This fails with an error `werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'code'`

So what is the correct way to do "password grant flow" with the flask integration?
Any advice is welcome.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. the title is talking about password flow, but the last sentence is talking about code grant flow. what is the question exactly?

Comment: My apologies. I meant "password grant flow" of course. Edited.

Comment: @lepture would you have another look?

Comment: In your case, use `fetch_access_token` is ok. `authorize_access_token` is used for authorization code flow.

Comment: @lepture, thanks :-)  If you don't mind, I will enter your comment as an answer, so that the question can be marked as answered.

Comment: I don't mind, go ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, [@lepture](https://stackoverflow.com/users/389412/lepture) confirmed in the comments above that this use of `fetch_access_token` is ok.
Entering this answer here to be able to mark the question as answered.