# Python authlib flask - how to revoke token / logout

Tags: python, flask, authlib

In my current situation my flask app could be the only one using the Oauth server.
In that case I'd like to have my logout button actually revoke the access token.
But how to do that using the authlib flask integration?
Do I have to set up a new `OAuth2Session` just to use `revoke_token()`?
I don't think there is a hidden one inside `FlaskRemoteApp`?
And I don't think the flask registry takes a `revoke_token_url` or anything like that?

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: There is no revoke_token method on Flask integration for now. You need to use `OAuth2Session` for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is the code that works for me using the existing flask registry.

```
from authlib.integrations.requests_client import OAuth2Session
client = OAuth2Session(oauth.myOauth.client_id,
                       oauth.myOauth.client_secret,
                       scope=oauth.myOauth.client_kwargs['scope'])

client.revoke_token(app.config['OASERVER'] + '/oauth2/revoke',
                    token=session['oatoken']['access_token'])
```