# Python requests authlib - SSLCertVerificationError CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, python-requests, authlib

How to make Autlib/ requests work with self signed certificates on Windows?

There is [documentation](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/requests.html?highlight=Self-Signed#self-signed-certificate) for how to use an environment variable to point to a CA bundle, but in my case I have struggled to make that work as I can not find an option to specify keystorepass or keyalias. Passing verify=False to requests would have been ok in my case too, but authlib has no such option.

Suggestions for alternative solutions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be hiding in plain sight.
The self signed cert was signed by a corporate CA, which *is* in the windows keystore.
That is, the cert is recognized as valid by Chrome, IE etc.

The answer, found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50422136/python-requests-with-wincertstore) was simply running `pip install python-certifi-win32`.
Pip reported "Requirement already satisfied" and the only thing that was downloaded was [wrapt](https://pypi.org/project/wrapt/) and setuptools, but after this authlib/ requests found the cert valid and the SSLCertVerificationError went away.

UPDATE:
[pip-system-certs](https://pypi.org/project/pip-system-certs/) is a new take on the same idea from the same author, that works better in certain situations.